# Calling base class methods with interface reference variable

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have a base class and an interface. Now I am creating a subclass from these. If I create a reference variable of the interface type to point to an object of the child class, can I access the base class methods using it?

```
Class BaseClass
{
public void baseClassMethod()
{
.....
}
}  
Interface MyInterface
{
public void Interfacemethod();
}


Class ChildClass:BaseClass, MyInterface
{
....

}


....


main()
{
MyInterface myclass= new ChildClass ();
myclass.baseClassMethod();//Is this possible? y?
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you try this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable `myclass` is statically typed as `MyInterface`, which does not have a method called `baseClassMethod()` - so no, that won't work. You would need to cast the reference back to `BaseClasss` or `Child` (either would be fine), or add the method to `MyInterface` (or some  additional interface).